# React-Apollo: Recommended way of subscribing to multiple events that doesn't require UI updates

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

So i want to subscribe to multiple events for the current logged user.

I've extracted the subscriptions to a separate function that update my logged user state from inside and returns an array of subscriptions.

Now i wanted to know is there a different / better way of doing this ?

Is this the correct / recommended way of approaching this problem ?

Current implementation

```
export const subscribeToCurrentUserUpdates = (setLoggedUser) => {
  const friendRequestObserver$ = apolloClient.subscribe(
    { query: queries.NEW_FRIEND_REQUEST },
  );
  const followersUpdatesObserver$ = apolloClient.subscribe(
    { query: queries.FOLLOWERS_UPDATES },
  );
  const acceptedFriendRequestObserver$ = apolloClient.subscribe(
    { query: queries.ACCEPTED_FRIEND_REQUEST },
  );

  const friendRequestSubscription = friendRequestObserver$.subscribe({
    next: ({ data: { newFriendRequest } }) => {
      Alert.success(`${newFriendRequest.username} just sent you a friend request`);

      setLoggedUser((loggedUser) => {
        loggedUser.incomingFriendRequests.unshift(newFriendRequest._id);
      });
    },
    error: err => console.error(err),
  });

  const followersUpdatesSubscription = followersUpdatesObserver$.subscribe({
    next: ({ data: { followersUpdates: { follower, isFollow } } }) => {
      if (isFollow) {
        Alert.success(`${follower.username} is now following you`);
      }

      setLoggedUser((loggedUser) => {
        isFollow
          ? loggedUser.followers.unshift(follower._id)
          : loggedUser.followers.splice(loggedUser.followers.indexOf(follower._id), 1);
      });
    },
    error: err => console.error(err),
  });

  const acceptedFriendRequestSubscription = acceptedFriendRequestObserver$.subscribe({
    next: ({ data: { acceptedFriendRequest: newFriend } }) => {
      Alert.success(`${newFriend.username} just accepted your friend request!`);

      setLoggedUser((loggedUser) => {
        loggedUser.friends.push(newFriend._id);
        loggedUser.sentFriendRequests.splice(
          loggedUser.sentFriendRequests.indexOf(newFriend._id), 1,
        );
      });
    },
    error: err => console.error(err),
  });

  return [
    friendRequestSubscription,
    followersUpdatesSubscription,
    acceptedFriendRequestSubscription,
  ];
};
```

The way i subscribe from my component

```
const App = () => {
  const currentUserSubscriptionRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loggedUser && !currentUserSubscriptionRef.current) {
      currentUserSubscriptionRef.current = subscribeToCurrentUserUpdates(
        setLoggedUser,
      );
    }
    if (!loggedUser && currentUserSubscriptionRef.current) {
      currentUserSubscriptionRef.current.forEach((subscription) => {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
      });
      currentUserSubscriptionRef.current = null;
    }
  }, [loggedUser, setLoggedUser]);
}
```